# d3 doesn't append circles on first run

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a nested dataset and the following code to draw circles in d3 v5:

```
const scatterGroup = svg.selectAll(".scatterGroup").data(data);

scatterGroup.exit().remove();

scatterGroup
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "scatterGroup")
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => color[i])
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => color[i])
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "scatterPoints");

const scatterPoints = scatterGroup
  .selectAll(".scatterPoints")
  .data((d) => d);

scatterPoints
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "scatterPoints")
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => xScale(d.x))
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => yScale(d.y))
  .attr("r", 5);

scatterPoints.exit().remove();

const scatterUpdate = scatterGroup
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => color[i])
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => color[i]);

scatterPoints
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => xScale(d.x))
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => yScale(d.y));
```

Nothing happens in the first run of providing the data. The control doesn't reach the append circle in the first load. When the data is loaded the second time, d3 appends the circles. Can anyone let me know on how to make them appear when the data is first provided and why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because the data is nested, so you need to [.merge()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) scatterGroup or re-select it before creating `scatterPoints`. Otherwise, `scatterGroup` is still empty, while `scatterGroup.enter()` holds all the points.

I also removed `.append(g).attr('class', 'scatterPoints')` from your code, since it uses a `g` instead of a `circle` and it doesn't need to be there

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const color = ['red', 'blue'];
const data = [
  [{
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 100
  }],
  [{
    x: 25,
    y: 50
  }]
];
const newData = [
  [{
    x: 10,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 50,
    y: 100
  }],
  [{
    x: 25,
    y: 40
  }]
];

function draw(data) {
  const scatterGroup = svg.selectAll(".scatterGroup").data(data);

  scatterGroup.exit().remove();

  const scatterGroupNew = scatterGroup
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "scatterGroup")
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => color[i])
    .attr("stroke", (d, i) => color[i]);

  // Equivalent:
  //const scatterPoints = svg.selectAll(".scatterGroup")
  //  .selectAll(".scatterPoint")
  //  .data((d) => d);

  const scatterPoints = scatterGroup
    .merge(scatterGroupNew)
    .selectAll(".scatterPoint")
    .data((d) => d);

  scatterPoints.exit().remove();

  const scatterPointsNew = scatterPoints
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "scatterPoint")
    .attr("r", 5);

  scatterPoints.merge(scatterPointsNew)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => d.x)
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => d.y);
}

draw(data);
setTimeout(() => draw(newData), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg>
</svg>
```